# Can I avoid bad/different rendering of FillPolygon versus DrawPolygon?

Tags: c#, graphics

I am using [FillPolygon](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.fillpolygon.aspx) with a semi-transparent color to draw a triangle (an arrow pointer). I have noticed that FillPolygon gives awkward results with an isocel triangle. One of the sides is overlapping [DrawPolygon](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.drawpolygon.aspx)'s side, while the two others aren't. I would have expected none or all, but not something in between.

Here's a sample: DrawPolygon uses a semi-transparent red, while FillPolygon uses a semi-transparent green. You can see one side is brown, the two other sides are red.

[alt text http://www.slimcode.com/downloads/arrow.png](http://www.slimcode.com/downloads/arrow.png)

The coordinates for this example are: {X=36,Y=201}, {X=42,Y=207}, {X=30,Y=207}.

Using an opaque color would solve everything as I could call both DrawPolygon and FillPolygon, but I need to use a semi-transparent color. I'm drawing into an image if it can make a difference.

Comment: please post two more pictures, one for each draw-op on its own.  Like you, I find this puzzling.  Unlike you, I don't have C# around.

Answer (score 1):

You want use a bitmap and do something like this. Note this is not runnable code.

```
    Dim image As New Bitmap(<my_Xsize>, <my_Ysize>)
    Dim gr As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(image)
    <Draw your FillPolygon>
    <Erase the leftside of the polygon>
    <Draw your Polygon>

     gr.DrawImage(image, <myXcoor>, <myYcoor>)
```

By using a bitmap you can fiddle down to the pixel level to get the exact thing you want.

Comment: That arrow can point in any direction, that's why it is drawn, but I will try rendering an image with a rotation, it's worth trying. No need for draw-erase-draw, a simple PNG image should be fine! Thanks!

Comment: The idea is that you use the bitmap as a intermediate drawing surface. So it will work in any direction.

Comment: I can't use this technique, as I'm not garanteed that it will always be the lest side that will look bad on all systems, all .NET fx versions, etc. It's better to use a static arrow PNG image and draw it with a RotateTransform.

Answer (score 0):

Hack: Draw the whole arrow as opaque in an intermediate buffer, then draw the whole buffer onto your image using the appropriate transparency.

Comment: No he suggests to erase the left side of the polygon, I suggest drawing it entirely without transparency on a intermediate buffer, then drawing the image in the buffer using the appropriate transparency.